# Can't connect to a computer that I can ping

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, raspberry-pi

I have two devices.  One is a Raspberry Pi and the other a full Linux computer from my school.  I am trying to establish a TCP socket connection between the two.  I can already do this between the Pi and another Pi, and likewise between the Linux box and another such box also belonging to the school.  What I cannot do is connect() between the Pi and the Linux box.  I can ping each from either, though, so I have reason to believe they are on the same network.  My guess is that there is a firewall blocking the Pi from connecting, but is there a better explanation?  How can I get the things talking?

Comment: you have a 10/100 or 10/100/1000 switch in between or trying to direct connect them?

Comment: Firewall sounds like the most likely explanation.

Comment: Yes, firewall is likely, but another possibility is NAT between them, and you have tested pinging the client from the server, but not the server from the client.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many possibilities. First, you should gather more diagnostic information.

Try `traceroute -n <ip>` to see the intermediate hosts. They could indeed be in a different local network with a filtering router between them.

Try connecting to the peer with `telnet <ip> <port>`. If it says `Connection refused`, it is likely that the other host is reachable, but there is nothing listening on the port. If there is no response (packet is dropped), it is likely a filter blocking the connection.

Next, try `nmap <ip>`. This will tell you which ports are open and blocked.

Examine IP filter rules:

```
iptables -L INPUT
```

on both hosts. You can remove all (input) rules with `iptables -F INPUT`. Make sure the default policy is accept `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`.

You could potentially be connecting to a different host entirely if it is a local address (most often 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x), and they are separated by a NAT. You could try blocking ping on the remote host temporarily to see if it has any effect:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
```

It should no longer be possible to ping the remote host. **Note:** Afterwards, re-enable ping with `sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=0`

Try a different TCP listening server, e.g. python's SimpleHTTPServer:

```
host1$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
host2$ telnet <ip> 8000
```

Comment: I'm out for the weekend now, but I look forward to trying it out.  Many thanks.  I'll go ahead and select this as an answer because I wanted a place to look and this is it.

Comment: This helped a lot. I have a remote Windows PC that was responding to ping but not ssh, which I use for games mostly and because my linux box Ubuntu distro is so old it can't be updated any more. I remoted into my linux box, ran nmap on the Windows machine, and found out that the vnc port was open. I vnc'd into my linux box, and then vnc'd into the Windows box to find it had rebooted without asking (grr) and was at the initial login prompt. From there I could login to Windows and start WSL which was providing my ssh server. This post was the key!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem.
On browser, it shows "This site can't be reached. x.x.x.x refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".
But on the terminal, I was able to ping the IP_Address.
One of the possible problems can be because of the firewall. 
Try to run these commands on the x.x.x.x machine terminal.

```
sudo firewall-cmd -state
systemctl stop firewalld
```

this will stop the firewall and now you can reload the browser URL. It will work if firewall was blocking access.
If this doesn't work, you can surely refer to another answer. I also tried it but got stuck at nmap command. "nmap - RTTVAR has grown to over 2.3 seconds, decreasing to 2.0"

Comment: Wow, taking me back to my senior design project... Pretty sure this already got resolved, and I graduated anyway :P but thanks for the response!